# how to access lable with id inside a div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to access the label with particular id inside the div "my_text" and
check whether text inside the each label matches with the "random text".
How can i achieve this?

```
<div id="my_text">
<div>
<lable id="0">sample text one</lable> 
<button id="0" type="button">×</button><br>
</div>
<div>
<lable id="1">sample text two</lable>
<button id="1" type="button">×</button><br>
</div>
</div>
```

/* here is my jquery code*/

```
if(($("#my_text > div > lable#id[i]").text() != "random text"))
 {
  $("#my_text").append('<div><lable id='+i+' >'+el.text+'</lable>'+'<button id='+i+' type="button">&times;</button><br></div>');
  }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Id attribute shoud be unique. Also you and select element only with it id `$('#id')`

Comment: Given that `id` attributes must be unique within the page you can just select by that: `$('#0')`

Comment: @Mohammad That is incorrect. IDs can start with numbers—that restriction is only applied to old browsers.

Comment: @Mohammad — Later part in your comment is not valid anymore.. [__`ID`__](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)

Comment: @Mohammad that's no longer the case in HTML5

Comment: `<lable>` is not a valid HTML element. I guess you meant to use `<label>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose what you're intending to do is to **iterate** through your collection of DOM nodes that matches the selector, and check if any of these labels contain the string `random text`. If they don't, you want to append a new element. Therefore, the strategy should be as follow:

1. Generate an array containing all the label text nodes. This is done using `.map().get()`, which returns an array.
2. Check if the returned array contains `random text`
3. If this condition is not met, append new element at the end. The ID of the new element is simply determined by the length of the array

Here is a proof-of-concept example:

```js
$(function() {
  // Retrieve all label text
  var labels = $('#my_text > div > label').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get();
  
  // Check if labels contain the string `random text`
  // If it is not found, append new component
  if(labels.indexOf('random text') < 0) {
    $('#my_text').append('<div><label id='+labels.length+' >label</label>'+'<button id='+labels.length+' type="button">&times;</button><br></div>');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_text">
  <div>
    <label id="0">sample text one</label>
    <button id="0" type="button">×</button>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label id="1">sample text two</label>
    <button id="1" type="button">×</button>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Do note that `<lable>` is not a valid HTML element. I suppose you meant to use `<label>` instead?

---

### Update: RegEx-based matching

If you intend to perform regular-expression based matching of label text, the process is similar but requires a bit of tweaking. As we cannot use `.indexOf()` to perform regex-based matching, it has to be performed at the iteration level. An example is as follow:

```js
$(function() {
  // Flag for regex match
  var match = false,
    pattern = /random text/gi;

  // Evaluate all label text
  var $labels = $('#my_text > div > label');
  $labels.each(function() {
    var regex = $(this).text().search(pattern);
    
    // Once a match is found, we toggle match to true
    // And return false to break out of the loop
    if (regex !== -1) {
      match = true;
      return false;
    }
  });

  // Check if any of the labels matches the regex pattern
  // If it is not found, append new component
  if (!match) {
    $('#my_text').append('<div><label id=' + $labels.length + ' >label</label>' + '<button id=' + $labels.length + ' type="button">&times;</button><br></div>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_text">
  <div>
    <label id="0">sample text one</label>
    <button id="0" type="button">×</button>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label id="1">sample text two</label>
    <button id="1" type="button">×</button>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm updating my answer now, just realised what OP really wants.

Comment: @Onera Glad that it worked. If you intend to perform regex-based matching (instead of exact string matches), I have also updated my answer to include that possibility, just in case ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.trim` and `.find`

```js
$(function(){
  
  var texting = "sample text one";
  
  if($('#my_text').find('label#0').text().trim() == texting) {
    console.log("Same");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_text">
<div>
<label id="0">sample text one</label> 
<button id="0" type="button">×</button><br>
</div>
<div>
<label id="1">sample text two</label>
<button id="1" type="button">×</button><br>
</div>
</div>
```